# How to define Square Root

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, branch-cuts

I'm trying to understand how to define the square root of a complex function "globally". Let's say we have some function from some set $X$ onto $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$: $$ f:X\to\mathbb{C}-\{0\} $$ and we define some number by $N(x) := \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)^2}}$.

It is clear that this number is always equal to plus or minus one: $ N(x)\in\{1,-1\}$.

However, what is unclear to me, is how to distinguish between these two cases, given a (complex) numerical value for $f(x)$.

I know that the square root of a complex number is only defined up to a sign: $\sqrt{z^2}=\pm z$ due to the multi-valuedness of the argfunction and the definition $$ z^n := \exp(\log(z^n)) = \exp(\log(|z|^n)+i \arg(z^n)) = |z|^n \exp(i \arg(z^n)) = |z|^n \exp(i n\varphi + in2\pi k)  \forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$$ where $\varphi\in[0,2\pi)$ is some angle we choose to represent $z$ and when $n=\frac{1}{2}$ we have only two distinct values of $k$, namely $k\in\{0,1\}$ so that $\sqrt{z} \in \{\sqrt{|z|} \exp(i\frac{\varphi}{2}), \sqrt{|z|} \exp(i(\frac{\varphi}{2}+\pi))\}$. where, again, $\varphi\in[0,2\pi)$ is some angle we choose to represent $z$.

The choice of which one of these possibilities we choose defines a branch, with $[0,\infty)$ being the branch cut, through which $\sqrt{}$ is not continuous.

What I don't understand is as follows:

I read in some paper (unrelated, physics) that "because $f$ is never zero globally and is continuous, we may define a global branch for the square root and it is uniquely defined in each point."

OK, so let's say we choose globally the first branch, in which $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{|z|} \exp(i\frac{\varphi}{2})$. Then how will we ever get $-1$ for $N(x)$? It seems to me like it will always be $+1$: $$ N(x) \equiv \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)^2}}  = \frac{|f(x)| \exp (i\varphi)}{\sqrt{|f(x)|^2 \exp (i 2 \varphi)}} = 1$$

How do you ever get -1???

Naively there must be some mistake in what I did because we know that if $f(x) = -2$ then $\sqrt{f(x)^2} = 2$ and so we get -1 indeed. But I cannot think of a general rule.

---

EDIT: Following a request, I am adding additional context and information about the actual problem at hand.

We assume there is a continuous map $f:\mathbb{T}^2\to\mathbb{C}^\ast$ where $\mathbb{T}^2$ is the 2-torus, and we are given the value of the function at four points on the torus: $\{f((0,0)), f((0,\pi)), f((\pi,0)), f((\pi,\pi))\}$, but not the actual map $f$.

How is it possible to then determine the sign of the following product: $$ \frac{f((0,0))}{\sqrt{f((0,0))^2}}\frac{f((0,\pi))}{\sqrt{f((0,\pi))^2}}\frac{f((\pi,0))}{\sqrt{f((\pi,0))^2}}\frac{f((\pi,\pi))}{\sqrt{f((\pi,\pi))^2}} $$?

Comment: @ PPR: I'm afraid for still missing some additional relation between the square roots of the four squares. Apparently, the function $f^2$ has two global square roots, namely $f$ and $-f$. In both cases the sign is $+1$. But that's trivial. Another question: What is your parametrization of the torus, is it $[0, 2\pi] \times [0, 2\pi]$?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the context itself. The article I am reading is this: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3895v2.pdf and the number I'm trying to compute is right above equation (10) on page 6. The parametrization for the torus is indeed as you wrote. As you yourself conclude, I was also wondering, how to obtain $-1$ from this computation, which is apparently a possibility.

Comment: The paper states that a global branch of the square root exists. Hence the first question is: How do they know? The torus is not simply connected, therefore they need some additional information about $\det \ w$. Secondly, in my opinion your question could be: When assuming the existence of a global continous square root of $det \ w$, how can one derive the value of the product of the four $\delta_a$?

Comment: Indeed the question if there is a global branch of the square root is a deep one, and relates to the symmetries of the problem, but they are working under the very assumption that this is possible. If we are indeed changing the question to what you suggest, how would you answer it?

Comment: It looks as if on hand hand, the authors have a global root of the determinant and on the other hand and independently, they know the value of the Pfaffian at 4 distinguished points. Both need not to match. The authors compute the quotient at each point and take the produce to obtain the characteristic number $\nu$ of the situation. I recommend to ask the authors themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The paper you read means the following: The squaring map

$$sq: \mathbb C^* \longrightarrow \mathbb C^*, sq(z):=z^2,$$

is a covering map in the sense of algebraic topology.

The set $\mathbb C$ is simply connected. Hence it has vanishing fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathbb C,*) = 0$. Therefore $f: \mathbb C \longrightarrow \mathbb C^*$ lifts to any covering of $\mathbb C^*$, in particular to the domain of $sq$: A continous map $g: \mathbb C \longrightarrow \mathbb C^*$ exists with $sq \circ g = f$, i.e. $g^2 = f$. A second lift differs by the sign, because you may choose one point $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ and prescribe one value

$$g(z_0) \in sq^{-1}(f(z_0))=\{ +\sqrt {f(z_0)}, -\sqrt {f(z_0) }\},$$

q.e.d.

**Note**. Concerning the lifting property see the lifting theorem, e.g., in "*Spanier, Edwin*: Algebraic Topology. Chap. 2, sect. 4, Theor. 5". The lifting theorem is a simple but powerful tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit confused. I know a little algebraic topology and covering maps. However, I'm still not sure about my particular question. First, is the map $f$ as you wrote it related to the map $f$ I have defined? If yes, why did you use it as $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}^\ast$ instead of $X\to\mathbb{C}^\ast$? Second, I don't understand what you mean by "A second lift differs by the sign"? You mean, another choice of $g$? Can you give a concrete example of such a map $f$ and concrete points where you'd get either $+1$ or $-1$? For concreteness, my set $X$ is the 2-torus.

Comment: For an example with $X = \mathbb C$ you may take $f(z)=exp \ z$. On $X$ there exist a square root as a global continous function $g$. If you have one square root you get the other as $-g$. But you are right, I consider the special case $X = \mathbb C$ or more general $X$ a connected, simply connected topological manifold. Apparently, a 2-torus $X$ is not simply connected, its fundamental group is the free product $\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$. By the lifting theorem a square root of $f$ exists iff $f$ induces a map $\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$ into the subgroup $2 \mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Z$.

Comment: So when you say a square root of $f$ exists, you mean globally? Also, I should mention that in fact I am not given the whole function $f$, but rather its value at four points on the torus, and I'm trying to decide what the value of $f(x_i)/\sqrt{f(x_i)^2}=\pm 1$ should be at each $i$. From your explanations, it is still not clear to me how to do so.

Comment: Yes, as square root of a gobal function I consider only a global function. You write in your question "globally". But your comment reads as if you look for the square root of 4 single complex numbers. I do not see if there is any relation between these numbers which should exist also between their square roots. Could you please edit in your question the whole problem with context?

Comment: I added some more context, let me know if it suffices or if you need more. Thanks for your help!